# How to use openssl with busybox's httpd?

Tags: https, openssl, apache, busybox

I have a busybox embedded device that provides http services with its built-in httpd. I want to provide https to improve its security, therefore I want to use openssl (or a similar software) with busybox httpd. On the internet there are a lot of tutorial for apache, tomcat and so on, but I'm not using these.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Busybox's httpd doesn't support SSL.  You can look at the [source code](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c) for the HTTP server and see that there are no hooks for SSL at all.

You'll have to use a different web server, like [mini httpd](http://www.acme.com/software/mini_httpd/).

Answer (score 6):

Busybox httpd does not support SSL; however, [Stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) can be used with it to provide SSL encryption. Stunnel acts as a "wrapper" which can be used to provide SSL encryption for services which do not support it natively.

An example: 4MLInux Server (a linux distro) uses httpd from Busybox, and Stunnel is used for the "https" protocol. More info can be found at [freecode](http://freecode.com/projects/4mlinux/releases/349434). An online demo is available here: http://server.4mlinux.com. (this example is from an editor via the stackexchange edit suggestion system)